# Android: Unresolved Dependencies

Tags: java, android, dependencies

I'm new to using android studio and basically I'm having a problem with my dependencies I'm not sure what happened but I've tried updating my gradle plugin version to 3.5.1 and the gradle version to 5.4.1 and still nothing happened. Also I've tried updating my SDK but its still giving me the same error.

ERROR:

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':robotutility@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :nerarosbridgeclient.
```

Here is my Build.Gradle Project:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

 }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
  }

     allprojects {
        repositories {
          google()
          jcenter()

    }
  }

   task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

& Build Gradle Module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.nerarobotics.robotutility'
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
    }
 }

 dependencies {
//noinspection DuplicatePlatformClasses
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

implementation 'com.jaredrummler:material-spinner:1.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
implementation project(path: ':nerarosbridgeclient')

}
```

Settings.gradle

```
include ':robotutility', ':nerarosbridgeclient'
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post your settings.gradle please

Comment: Is the project nerarosbridgeclient available in your workspace?

Comment: If `nerarosbridgeclient` project is available in your workspace, then you have to include it in `settings.gradle`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably project **`nerarosbridgeclient`** is not included in your `settings.gradle` or project missing in your workspace. Please check and update.

Add this line in `settings.gradle` if missing:

```
include ':nerarosbridgeclient'
```